# Installing php5.4 with postgresql pdo drivers

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I'm having trouble getting Apache2 started after compiling php5.4 with postgre pdo drivers, my error is:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 53 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: pdo_pgsql_module_entry
```

My configuration options were:
PHP config options:

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/bin/pg_config --with-pgsql=/usr/bin/pg_configure
```

Apache2 config options

```
./configure --enable-so --enable-mods-shared=/usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

Everything was running fine at first, before I added the pgsql flags to the php config, and then rebuilt.  Any ideas?

EDIT:
PHP seems to have installed correctly, it's just getting apache started:

```
$>php -i | grep -i pdo
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs' '--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/bin/pg_config' '--with-pgsql=/usr/bin/pg_configure'
PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the systems timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in Unknown on line 0
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => pgsql, sqlite
pdo_pgsql
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled
Revision =>  $Id: pdo_pgsql.c 314376 2011-08-06 14:47:44Z felipe $ 
pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

EDIT 2:
Here's line 53 + the other's I edited in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

---

Comment: What does line 53 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf look like?

Comment: Any reason why it's pg_config and pg_configure? Did you do a `make clean` when you rebuilt PHP? It is some times, in my experience, necessary to do that depending on what options have changed.

Comment: @decese: I added the relevant lines to my post, line 53 is the LoadModule line.

Comment: @Matthew: I will try `make clean` and report back.

Comment: @Matthew: `make clean` did the trick, can you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain options require a `make clean` when rebuilding PHP, particularly when tweaking something that depends on another component (e.g., adding a PDO driver to an install that already has the core PDO driver). A missing symbol is a sign of that.